# Sending Array of Objects to Web API from AngualrJS

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

During this process, I grab an array of "vehicles" from the Web API. I modify and do whatever to each vehicle. Then I want to send the list back, without going through and looping...

I've tried a lot of the ways that i've looked up. 
I've got this in the WEB API for a breakpoint to see if I can even get the array there, but I havent been able to yet.

```
   public IHttpActionResult UpdateVehicles(Vehicle[] vehiclesArry)
    {
        return Ok();
    }
```

I'm confused if I need to do a $post, or if I could just "get" it to the correct method like I've been doing. The problem is I can't get the array to the WEB API method.

I've got my $resource setup like this.

```
       return $resource(appSettings.serverPath + "/api/Violators/:id",null,
         {
             'update': { method: 'PUT' },
             'delete': { method: 'DELETE' },
             'post': { method: 'POST' }
         });
```

I've tried using $post, but it says the object doesn't support it. I'm not sure what other ways I can try. I've tried using "dynamic" in the web API, that doesn't seem to work either.

Comment: Why your resource route has an Id ? while your api method doesn't have an id ? can you show us how to call the put method ?

Comment: That Id is optional. I haven't had issues doing updates, posts or anything until I wanted to send an array of objects to the api

Answer (score 0):

Create a model object like

```
public class UpdateReq  
{
    public IEnumerable<Vehicle> Vehicles { get; set; }
}
```

From your angular, just pass a json with an array

```
{
   [v1, v2, v3]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're missing the params object for $resource, so it doesn't know the id.

```
return $resource(appSettings.serverPath + "/api/Violators/:id", { id: '@id' });
```

You don't need to explicitly setup methods for get, post, delete. That's already done for you. If your API uses PUT for update, set that up like this:

```
return $resource(appSettings.serverPath + "/api/Violators/:id", { id: '@id' }, {
   update: { method: 'PUT' }
});
```

Also, the property on your resource must be `vehiclesArry` exactly or web API won't know how to map it. I also want to echo @sowen. You will need to setup a view model that your endpoint receives.

Answer (score 0):

My assumption is that you are having some script errors in your page or you are not using the $http methods properly.

One problem people usually run into is using the correct url to the web api endpoints in your angular controller. If you don't get it right, you might be getting 404 errors. Look for those in your browser console(network tab)

The below code should work fine without any issues

```
$http.get("../api/Values/")
    .then(function (res) {

        var vehicles = res.data;
        console.log('data received', JSON.stringify(vehicles));

        //Let's update the Name of each vehicle.
        $.each(vehicles, function (indx, item) {
            item.Name = item.Name + " Updated";
        });

        console.log('data modified', JSON.stringify(vehicles));

        //Let's make a call to web api with modified data
        $http.post("../api/Values/UpdateVehicles", vehicles)
            .then(function (res2) {
                console.log('response', JSON.stringify(res2.data));
            });

    });
```

Assuming you have angular js properly loaded in your page and the above code is part of your angular controller for the current page and you have the Web api controller with 2 action methods like below example.

```
public class ValuesController : ApiController
{
    [HttpPost]
    [Route("api/Values/UpdateVehicles")]
    public IHttpActionResult UpdateVehicles(Vehicle[] vehiclesArry)
    {
        // just returning whatever came in for TESTING PURPOSE
        return Ok(vehiclesArry);
    }
    public IEnumerable<Vehicle> Get()
    {
        return new List<Vehicle>
        {
             new Vehicle {Id = 1, Name = "Car"},
             new Vehicle {Id = 2, Name = "Van"}
        };
     }
}
```

Also,FYI : I am using [Attribute routing](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2) in my api controller for the `UpdateVehicle` endpoint.